# pattern for building objects that contain other objects which contain their parents

Tags: design-patterns

This question is difficult to articulate but here goes:

I have a set of classes with the following relationship :

[image: diagram]

The issue comes when I'm trying to access the data. I'm trying to do this as efficiently as possible. The user should be able to look up a course and its sections, a professor and its sections, a section and its students (implying a professor/student relationship), a section and its professor (a section doesn't have more than one professor). Also sections don't care about which courses they belong to but courses do care about their sections.

I should be able to say, for example, `professorA.listSections()`; or `professorA.listSections()` etc.

I'm honestly not sure how to go about doing this in an efficient manner (if there is one). Any design patterns or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already mapped out most of the things, now all you have to do is connect between the entities:

- Each professor object should have a list of courses that he teaches.
- Each Student object should have a list of courses that he studies.

But on the Student case - he should have something "extra": since every course could be taught by more than one Professor, the Student needs a way to "know" which professor teaches the course each he takes (another "extra" field).

I'm not sure I understand the sections thing - but it can be done in the same manner.

Comment: sections are specific instances of courses. So section 123123 could correspond to a calculus 1 course and section 21349028498 could correspond to a calc1 course or a calc 2 course. Professors only implicitly teach courses but they actually teach sections (of which have courses). It's just that the linking is what I'm having an issue with. Could I perhaps have sections inherit courses and then use reflection some kind of way?

Comment: If a section could refer to more than one course (like your second example here) then it can't be an instance of a course: how would you know if a student that took section 21349028498 took calc1 or calc2 ?

Comment: Sorry I meant inherited. So then a student taking section 213 would be in calc 1  because section 213 is derived from the calc 1 course. Essentially the section's base would determine the course.

Comment: In that case each student object should hold a list of `sections` - not a list of courses. And it would be a good idea that each section will also hold the course # as well as the section-id.